# std::get_time failing on Visual C++ 2017

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to parse a simple date time string using `std::get_time` on Windows but it does not work and I don't know why.

When I debug I can see that only the hours, minutes and seconds are correctly parsed, but not the rest.

The call to 'str_stream.fail()' returns always true.

I would like to avoid using `boost::date_time` and try to solve this issue.

Reading a detail from the reference, could it be something to do with std::locale of `std::time_get facets`? If so how to set that correctly?

I'd like to parse that date and time as UTC.

I am using Visual C++2017 under Windows 10.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <ctime>

int main() {
    std::string tmp("20180102 12:24:33");
    std::stringstream str_stream(tmp);      
    tm data;
    str_stream >> std::get_time(&data, "%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S");
    if (str_stream.fail())  {
        std::cout << "failed" << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "success" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Added compilable example. This does work with GCC 7.2.0

Comment: `tm data;` may not initialize all of `data`.  Suggest zero filling before `std::get_time(&data,...`

Comment: @chux I don't see how that could affect writing to a `tm` structure.

Comment: `"20180102 12:24:33"` looks like a year in the far future with no month nor day.  Maybe `"2018 01 02 12:24:33"?

Comment: @chux It looks like 2018 01 02 (with no spaces between the elements) to me. And as I pointed out, this code does work with GCC.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Filling `data` with something can help in debugging in determining what was written with `get_time()`.

Comment: @Neil Correct. I did ask explicitly for Visual C++ as the code that works on LInux doesn't in WIndows..and I need it in Windows unfortunately.

Comment: ..so what's the point in using the formatting string "%Y%m%d" if then I have to change the input string? my doubt is that I am missing something on the usage of this function. I took a look at std::time_get::get_date and facets but seems rather complicated (I need a bit to digest it)

Comment: @AbruzzoForteeGentile Tagging this post as  Visual C++ (the compiler) is more useful than tagging as windows (the OS).

Comment: Works for me with VS 2015. I don't have VS 2017 installed.

Comment: @chux correct : tag updated

Comment: @Neil the sample code prints `success` in my VS2017, however subsequent `std::cout << data.tm_mon << " " << data.tm_mday;` prints `-858993460 -858993460`

Comment: @lukeg Well, we can only answer questions on what the OP asks. He said fail() was returning true.

Comment: probably related - [MSConnect 3093410 | c++ std::get_time not parsing correctly](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/140618/c-stdget-time-not-parsing-correctly.html). Also cppreference states that it is a good idea to initialize `tm` prior to calling this function.

Comment: "When I debug I can see that only the hours, minutes and seconds are correctly parsed, but not the rest." --> what do you see in the rest?

Comment: tm_year = -85000, tm_month = -85000, tm_day = -850000 ..all other fields are set tot his value (I dont have the exact value with me and I can't access my Win Pc unfortunately)

Comment: @AbruzzoForteeGentile in debug build uninitialized `data` is filled with `0xCC` pattern which produces `-858993460` value (garbage).

Comment: ..Ok, so I need to re-try initializing tm data = {0}

Comment: @AbruzzoForteeGentile Certainly parsing is amiss due to the packed `"%Y%m%d"` and `"20180102"`.  This may be due to a mis-implementation of `get_time()` or a lax specification.  I suspect it is both.  Try working with one or two specifiers at a time to narrow the cause.